# Linq to SQL varbinary returns null if called by WCF service?

Tags: wpf, wcf, linq-to-sql

I came into a strange situation today when I was trying to retrieve data from the Sql Server 2008 database using Linq2Sql.

Data = couple of products. It is simple table with fields such as: productID, product name, product description and product picture. The picture is stored as a BLOB (Varbinary(MAX)) type in the database.

There is also a stored procedure in the database for geting all the products.

In Linq to SQL dbml file, return type of Varbinary(MAX) is set as System.Data.Linq.Binary.

Now, everything works fine when I query database via WPF application as a top layer - product list is received correctly along with Binary data representing picture, but when I call the same stored procedure via WCF service as a top layer, Binary data all of a sudden become 'null' value!!!

All the other data such as product name, description etc is present, but pictures are just missing?

Does anybody know what is the problem here? Or should I simply switch to EF?

Regards..

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the [DataMember] attribute to the field that contians your binary data?

Comment: No I haven't actually.. But I moved in the meantime to the Entity Framework, and the problem disappeared. EF seems to be better choice after all! Thanks anyway!